# Simplify in the form: $x^n + \frac{1}{x^n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Simplify: $$\left(x^2 + \sqrt2 + \frac{1}{x^2}\right)\left(x^2 - \sqrt2 + \frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ in the form $x^n + \frac{1}{x^n}$

Comment: I think you can just expand it

Comment: Do you know distributive law?

Comment: We need more answers!

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align} & \left(x^2 + \sqrt2 + \frac{1}{x^2}\right)\left(x^2 - \sqrt2 + \frac{1}{x^2}\right) \\ &
=\left(x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}\right)^2 - \left(\sqrt2\right)^2 \\ &
=\left(x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}\right)^2 - 2 \\ &
=x^4 + \frac{1}{x^4} + 2 - 2 \\ &
=x^4 + \frac{1}{x^4} \end{align}$$

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(x^2 + \sqrt2 + \frac{1}{x^2}\right)\left(x^2 - \sqrt2 + \frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$

=$$\left(x^2  + \frac{1}{x^2}+\sqrt2\right)\left(x^2  + \frac{1}{x^2}-\sqrt2\right)$$

What can you say about the form:

$$(a-b)(a+b)$$

Answer (score 2):

One may write
$$
\begin{align}
\left(x^2 + \sqrt2 + \frac{1}{x^2}\right)\left(x^2 - \sqrt2 + \frac{1}{x^2}\right)&=\left(x^2  + \frac{1}{x^2}+ \sqrt2\right)\left(x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} - \sqrt2\right)
\\&=\left[\left(x^2  + \frac{1}{x^2}\right)^2- 2\right]
\\&=x^4+2  + \frac{1}{x^4}- 2
\\&=x^4  + \frac{1}{x^4}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align} &  
\left(x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}\right)^2 - \left(\sqrt2\right)^2 \\ &
=x^4 + \frac{1}{x^4} +2 \cdot \frac{1}{x^2} \cdot x^2  -\left(\sqrt2\right)^2 \\ &
=x^4 + \frac{1}{x^4} +2 -2 \\ &
=x^4 + \frac{1}{x^4}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Would you mind expanding a bit? What's the relation of your formula to the one in the OP? I see that you're using $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2 - b^2$, but I don't know if this is obvious.

Comment: No,I am at first expanding  $ ( a+b) ( (a-b) $ and the using term by term squaring of first term so that reciprocals cancel out in multiplication .